# Analyse monthly sale in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data set like this

```
  order_status  created_at
0    cancelled  05/08/2018
1    cancelled  06/08/2018
2   dispatched  27/08/2018
3   dispatched  30/08/2018
4    cancelled  05/09/2018
5   dispatched  05/09/2018
6   dispatched  25/09/2018
7    cancelled  23/10/2018
8   dispatched  05/10/2018
9   dispatched  02/08/2018
```

where the date format is dd/mm/yy. What I want is to analyze the data based on month, like how many orders were cancelled in 8th month of the year, how many were dispatched in 9th month of the year. What I'm doing is something like this

```
df2 = df[['order_status','created_at']].\
         set_index('created_at').\
         resample('M')
df2.iplot(kind='bar', xTitle='Date', yTitle='Order Status',
    title='Monthly Order Status')
```

but it's throwing error

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

what can i do to get the monthly report of all the orders?

Comment: you need an aggregation function after `resample` ie `...resample('M').sum()` for example. You'll need to pivot this data first though

Comment: yeah, but I'm using categorical value (cancelled,dispatched) for analysis

Comment: Yes, you should `pivot` first, with status across columns and date as row index. try using `pandas.crosstab`- so putting it all together, try `pd.crosstab(df['created_at'], df['order_status']).resample('M').sum().plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])    
f = df.groupby(df.created_at.dt.month)['order_status'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')

      created_at order_status  count
0           2   dispatched      1
1           5    cancelled      2
2           5   dispatched      2
3           6    cancelled      1
4           8   dispatched      2
5           9   dispatched      1
6          10    cancelled      1

# plot
f.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi , thanks for the response, how can I plot this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.datetime` methods to obtain che month from a date.

```
df['month'] = df['created_at'].map(lambda x: x.month)
```

After that, by means of `value_counts`, you can count how many orders are canceled or dispatched this way:

```
df[df['dispatched']=='cancelled']['month'].value_counts()
```

Hope it helps.

**NB**:

If you have different years in your date, you can use some math manipulation to have information of both year and month:

```
df['year_month'] = df['created_at'].map(lambda x: 100*x.year + x.month)
```